# Linux: cat /dev/video0 TS into some kind of ring puffer

Tags: linux, cat

I want to cat a /dev/video0 device output (Transport Stream) into a temporary ring buffer. In fact i do not want that the file is growing over the time. Simultaneously access is not possible.

So the purpose is to have a file (buffer, Fifo, whatever) to be accessed by more than one consumer (example: tail -f, mencoder, VLC, ....).

```
Some kind of scenario: 
1# cat /dev/video0 > mybuffer.ts
And then multiple access
2# tail -f mybuffer.ts > extract1.ts
2# tail -f mybuffer.ts > extract2.ts
3# ffmpeg ...
```

Does someone have an idea how to do something like this?

Comment: How would the ring buffer know when all of the clients have connected to it?

Comment: Does the ring buffer has to know? I start the "producer" and the /dev/video0 output will be continuously written into the buffer. The consumers grabs the data from the buffer.

Comment: How will the buffer know that it can release old data?

Comment: The buffer can release older data after a certain file size is reached (for example). 1MB, 10MB ... in fact i just need the kind of "buffer" to create a point/file/source to grab data from multiple consumers because /dev/video0 does allow only 1 consumer.

Comment: But what if another consumer wants its contents after the certain size is reached?

Comment: Consumers are grabbing just the newest data/last inserted stream images (tail -f). If file size is reached, the oldest data in the buffer will be thrashed. A consumer never grabs images older than "now" or seeks inside the buffer.